# How much RAM and CPU throughput can handle 20GE in Cloud?

Tags: networking, hardware, cloud

We're going to build a cloud infrastructure and would like to use the HP DL160 G8 with a 20GE NIC (2x10GE LACP).

How much RAM and CPU can handle this NIC?

The server will have at least 2x Intel E5-2640 and 256 GB RAM. The maximum amount of RAM is 768GB.

We want to use this Infrastructue for usual Customers as Privat/Public Cloud Solution.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: SPending money, not knowing what you do - time to hire a professional.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really make sense, but I'm going to try and give you a straight cut answer anyway.

Assuming you're using the [NC523SFP](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/10294823) (big assumption), these (as does every 10Gb NIC I've ever seen) have an offload engine. Some even have such powerful processors they have a fan on their substantial heatsinks.

This takes processing load off the main processor, which means that you should be able to saturate your 20Gb/s of bandwidth (if you can even generate that much data) with only dedicating a minimum of your processor time to it.

(for what it's worth, it's difficult to saturate even a single 10Gb link).

Comment: Hey,

sorry for my bad English((

Anyways, we think that our cloud will generate enough data!

If a customer have a heavy application which requires lots of RAM (let's say database) and need to caching ~1TB, you think that just 10GE would be enough?

Comment: Sigh. Why would the RAM requirements of a database have anything to do with the bandwidth of the network?